# Return not only the changed values using DirSync in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, synchronization

I use the System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirSyncRequestControl with a cookie to sync only the objects which were changed since the last sync from Active Directory to a SQL-Database. On first sync (cookie is null) everythings works fine, but on a later diff-sync the search only return the changed attributes of the object and not the whole list of properties I asked for.

```
SearchRequest Request = new SearchRequest(RootDSE.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString(), "(|(objectClass=user)(objectClass=group)(objectClass=contact))", System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree, propertiesToLoad);
                    DirSyncRequestControl DirSyncRC = new DirSyncRequestControl(cookie, System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectorySynchronizationOptions.None, Int32.MaxValue);
                    Request.Controls.Add(DirSyncRC);

                    SearchResponse SearchResponse = (SearchResponse)Connection.SendRequest(Request);

                    foreach (SearchResultEntry Entry in SearchResponse.Entries)
                    {
    ...
    }
```

I thought that setting the DirectorySynchronizationOptions to None would work but unfortunately it doesn't.

So is there a way to always return a full set of definded attributes if even one of the attribute changes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Dirsync control will return you only attributes that were changed. To get additional user properties you have 2 options:
1. Make an additional LDAP query to retrieve attributes needed.
2. Use usn based change tracking technique